# How to reset the ink level of a Black HP 652 Cartridge installed on a HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 2136 All-In-One Printer?

Tags: inkjet-printer, cartridge, hp-deskjet

I used to have an older HP Printer and I refilled the ink cartridge at home and it worked perfectly.

However on this newer printer after I refilled the cartridge the printer does not recognize that the cartridge is full. It says it is empty and it does not print black ink at all.

Comment: If you filled the cartridge improperly, the printer may not print. The ink sometimes doesn't flow to the bottom of the reservoir. Check it once.

Comment: How to check this? .....  Anyway. I am almost sure this is not the problem. At my last printer I had to reset the cartridge and the it printed. The problem is that I do not know how to reset this type of cartridge and there is no information on the Internet. I used to have an HP 21 and HP 22 cartridges. I followed this tutorial https://thehiccup.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/how-to-reset-hp-ink-level-hp-2728-and-hp-2122/ and then it worked.

Comment: Most of these cartridges now contain a chip that monitors usage and decides when it's empty.  For some popular cartridges, you can buy a 3rd party device that resets the chip so the cartridge reads as full if you refill it.  Some printers (I'm guessing ones destined for the US market), provide instructions for disabling the printer's reliance on the chip so you can use 3rd-party/refilled cartridges, although they include warnings of dire consequences and potential loss of warranty.  I couldn't find any of that for this printer, and the user manual says all bets are off for refilled cartridges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called a printer company and they told me that the HP 652 Black and Color cartridges are NOT locked when the printer reads them as empty. They should still print normally.

The problem was that the cartridge was actually empty not filled. 
Apparently I had very little ink in the bottle and when I pulled ink from the syringe it appeared as full because the syringe was sucking some drops of ink and appeared full at the walls.

I just refilled with full ink syringe and it worked just fine .... so the cartridge is OK and it does not need any kind of re-setting.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The cartridge is full to the top and it still displays it as empty.